# Put buttons on a banner in jade

Tags: html, css, button, pug, banner

I want to put buttons on a banner using jade. My goal is to have 4 buttons side by side with a banner on the background for the whole line.

But when I put the buttons on the banner div, I see them but I can't click on them. I don't understand why. I have search in html and I see the same thing that I have done in jade but for me it doesn't work..
Someone can help ?
This is my jade and css

jade

```
    doctype html
html

head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    .banner
        h1 title
    .banner_2
        button(onclick="home()") Accueil
        button(onclick="newuser()") Nouveau libraire
        button(onclick="listuser()") Liste des libraires
        button(onclick="newbook()") Nouveau livre
        button(onclick="listbook()") Liste des livres
        button(onclick="login()") Connexion
        button(onclick="signup()") Inscription
body
    block content
    
script.
    function newuser() { 
        window.location.href = '/newuser'
    }
        function listuser() {
        window.location.href = '/userlist'
    }
        function newbook() {
        window.location.href = '/newbook'
    }
        function listbook() {
        window.location.href = '/booklist'
    }
```

css

```
.button {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out, color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #70c7be;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 0;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 2.85em;
    line-height: 2.95em;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.banner_2 {
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0.25em ;
    min-height: 5vh;
    background-color: #5Ea7B6;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Divs should never go in the `head` element. They belong in the `body`.